# automatically printing page on form submit

Tags: php, javascript

i have been using the below code to automatically print out a form on submission but the problem i have encountered is that upon navigating away from the page, the "Submit - And Print" button stops working.

Secondly is there a way to bypass the print dialog on internet explorer/google chrome and allow the form to print automatically and the send the request to the printer automatically? there is also a need to remove all headers and footers from the pages pritned (i.e. internet explorer web page printing defaults).

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function PrintMeSubmitMe()
{
window.print();
SubmitMe();
}

function SubmitMe()
{
document.MyForm.submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="MyForm" action="somepage.asp" method="post">
<input type="button" value="Submit - No Print" onclick="SubmitMe()"><br />
<input type="button" value="Submit - And Print" onclick="PrintMeSubmitMe(this)"><br />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

i have come to realise that the "submit - and print" bug occurs on google chrome only and not internet explorer

Comment: For security reasons you cannot remove the print dialog. Only the user can decide whether he wants to allow or not printing.

Comment: how do point of sale units operate then?

Comment: They install proprietary plugins on the client computers like ActiveX, Flash, Silverlight, ... and of course restrict the browsers to only a specific one. Don't expect this on any public web site unless of course they force you to install something to make the magic happen on the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On IE you can install a plugin from [MeadCo](http://www.meadroid.com/) (a UK based company) which includes an embedded object and comprehensive javascript interface to the printer that allows control of almost all aspects of printing. We have been using this solution for many years now and it would probably meet your needs of avoiding the print dialog, managing header/footer, etc.

Answer (score 4):

There is **no** way to bypass the print dialog.* If there was a way, it could be maliciously exploited far too easily. It would be a **security nightmare**.

---

*Without a browser plugin

Comment: Are there any generic browser plugins that would allow automatic printing on Google Chrome (i.e. skip print preview page)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using chrome, you can disable print preview dialog.

```
1. Create shortcut of chrome
2. Go to properties
3. Add "--disable-print-preview" at the end of target
   or
   Add "--koisk-printing" at the end of target
```